# WPF Menu arrow on the first level

Tags: wpf, templates, menu, styles, menuitem

Help me please with wpf menu. 
I want the arrows showing that a menu item has also subitems. 
By default these arrows get placed beginning on the second level. but I want them to be shown on the first level also.

I don't clearly understand what to change and how. Although I found

```
<Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
```

inside the item's template, but I couldn't that make to work for me.

UPD: I tried to do that:

```
 <Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

And now I have some crap like that:

[image]

You see I don't like the second element's offset. I don't know how to align that to the left. 
I tried to change Padding, Margin, HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAligment - nothing helped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517279/wpf-c-change-the-brush-of-a-menus-background
this may help

Comment: Why you commented, isn't that the answer? Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems they aligned properly when icons added.