# How to style menu item background

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, background

I can't figure out how to change the background from the boring gray color to something else. When I change the `MenuItem`s background it is only the items background itself that is changed and not the whole background. Do someone know how to style it?

Here is an image of my current menu:

[image]

I can do this but what about the border?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />    
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

MSDN: [Menu Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296.aspx)

Comment: When I do that the menu is all gone.

Comment: @FireFly3000 : what you mean by `all gone`?

Comment: BTW, have you set OverridesDefaultStyle = true?

Comment: I am not allowed to add the based on property. When I do the targetType sends this error: Target type System.Windows.Controls.Menu is not convertible to base type System.String ???

Comment: When I follow your code the menu disappears. When I remove the override line the background is changed on each Item but there is still a border around the menu. I have added an image of this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Menu Background="Gray" Height="23">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu1" Background="Green">
                <MenuItem Header="sub1" Background="Red"/>
                <MenuItem Header="sub2" Background="Yellow"/>
            </MenuItem>
     </Menu>
```

[image]

**Update:**
My above solution won't change the WHOLE background as your mentioned. 
To have a whole new style read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/519012/352101

Comment: yes, but as you can see there is still a border around the sub menus which in my case is gray.