# How to change the background of the MenuItem on MouseOver in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem

Reading lots of stuff and asking a bunch of questions I have finally put together a new style for my `Menu/MenuItem` in `WPF`.

But I'm stuck where I want to change the background and border of a single submenu when it is highlighted.

In the image below, I want the blue background to be changed to say yellow!

[image]

Here is the complete working code so far:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#939393" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#717171" Offset="0.05"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#606060" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Clicked" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#363636" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#393939" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>


        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Menu">
                        <Border x:Name="MainMenu" Background="#535353">
                            <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                    BorderBrush="#535353" 
                    CornerRadius="3" 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"  AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#595959" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3A3A3A" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#2C2C2C"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="1"></Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Clicked}" />
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Test" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2C2C2C"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#535353">
        <Menu Width="100" Height="22" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="mm" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
                <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
                <MenuItem Header="_Copy"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Cut"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Paste"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Did you see following links?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517279/wpf-c-sharp-change-the-brush-of-a-menus-background

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783705/how-to-set-foreground-and-background-colors-on-a-wpf-menu-control

Comment: How are you getting the dark background in your drop down menu? I replicated your code and mine is white still, despite yours clearly being dark.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. You're just adding the template to the root; not the children MenuItems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make another template. Here is one with the background yellow, border orange and text black.

Look at MenuItemControlTemplate2, the IsHighlighted trigger.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#939393" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#717171" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#606060" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Clicked" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#363636" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#393939" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>


    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Menu">
                    <Border x:Name="MainMenu" Background="#535353">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                BorderBrush="#535353" 
                CornerRadius="3" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"  AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#595959" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3A3A3A" Padding="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#2C2C2C"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="1"></Setter>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Clicked}" />
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="Test" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2C2C2C"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate2" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="menuHeaderContainer" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="#535353">
    <Menu Width="100" Height="22" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="mm" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Close" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Cut" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Paste" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks J.H., this completely solved my problem. Just a little question. As you can see in the image above the big gray rectangle containing the submenues is a little off to the right. I want it to be exactly under the main menu. Which part of the template should I edit?

Comment: @Vahid - You're welcome. The submenus are part of the Popup in MenuItemControlTemplate1 (1 NOT 2). So, at the end of the <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" element, add  HorizontalOffset="-2". That whole element should look like this now: <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" HorizontalOffset="-2">

Comment: FYI - There is a VerticalOffset too, if you wanted to move the submenus up/down.

Comment: Thank you so much J.H., you have valuable information regarding WPF. Can you recommend me a book/article specific to the subjects discussed here?

Comment: A book/article? I've never read a book on WPF so I can't really recommend one. I learn by doing and searching Google (and using my past experience programming, of course).

Comment: I'll do the same then ;)

Comment: Click on menu item but don't click on submenu, after that if mouse over position is moved from menu, the background color is not back into initial one (without hover). anyone can answer why? thanks.