# How to insert an icon in the Menu Item using control template

Tags: wpf

My GUI contains a drop down menu. The root menu item contains only an icon. I want to insert an icon (`"M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z"`) in the following control template taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24699287/12526953). I am not able insert an icon in the menu item using an user defined control template. How can this be done?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                BorderBrush="#535353" 
                CornerRadius="3" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"  AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" HorizontalOffset="-2">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#595959" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3A3A3A" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#2C2C2C"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="1"></Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Clicked}" />
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Test" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2C2C2C"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I think you can insert `<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}">` before ContentPresenter.

Comment: @ emoacht, can you please tell where do I specify the SVG code (`"M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z"`) for the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>` before ContentPresenter and set `MenuItem.Icon` property an object valid for `Image.Source`.

In the case of path data, you can use `DrawingImage` and create a Style using this ControlTemplate like the following.

```xml
<Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z"
                                     Brush="Red"/>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```