# Icon only displayed when IsCheckable=true for MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, wpf-style

I used the code form the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517279/wpf-c-sharp-change-the-brush-of-a-menus-background) to build my own itemmenu.
The problem is that the top-most-item should only have an icon as content. but if I do this, the icon is not displayed, unless I also set isCheckable=true.
This is the code that I changed sightly.

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
          <Border x:Name="Border"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <!-- ContentPresenter to show an Icon if needed -->
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>

          <!-- Glyph is a checkmark if needed for a checkable menu -->
          <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
          </Grid>

          <!-- Content for the menu text etc -->
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            x:Name="HeaderHost"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            ContentSource="Header"/>

          <!-- Content for the menu IGT -->
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="8,1,8,1"
                            x:Name="IGTHost"
                            ContentSource="InputGestureText"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

          <!-- Arrow drawn path which points to the next level of the menu -->
          <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
          </Grid>

          <!-- The Popup is the body of the menu which expands down or across depending on the level of the item -->
          <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2,2,2,2">
              <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                <!-- StackPanel holds children of the menu. This is set by IsItemsHost=True -->
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </Popup>
        </Grid>
      </Border>

      <!-- These triggers re-configure the four arrangements of MenuItem to show different levels of menu via Role -->
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- Role = TopLevelHeader : this is the root menu item in a menu; the Popup expands down -->
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
          <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
          <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" TargetName="Col0"/>
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" TargetName="Col3"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="IGTHost"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Role = TopLevelItem :  this is a child menu item from the top level without any child items-->
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Role = SubMenuHeader : this is a child menu item which does not have children -->
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
          <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Role = SubMenuItem : this is a child menu item which has children-->
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
          <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- If no Icon is present the we collapse the Icon Content -->
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- The GlyphPanel contains the CheckMark -->
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Using the system colors for the Menu Highlight and IsEnabled-->
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedText}"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SolidMenuFontBrush}"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

In the actual UserControl the menuitems are used like this:

```
 <Menu x:Name="myMenu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                <MenuItem Height="25" Width="30" Header="" IsCheckable="True">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/Tool;component/Resources/help.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="btAbout" Header="About" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="btHelp" Header="Documentation" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="btBugReport" Header="Bug report" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="btFeatureRequest" Header="Feature request" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
```

What changes are necessary so that the Icon is always displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `IsCheckable` property anywhere in your Control Template, but your problem is probably related with both the Icon and the GlyphPanel (for the check mark) being on the same `Grid.Column`.

Add a new `ColumnDefinition` to the Grid for your Icon:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuCustomIconColumnGroup" />
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And set the `Grid.Row` values accordingly for all the affected controls. For instance:

```
<!-- Glyph is a checkmark if needed for a checkable menu -->
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Comment: to be honest i dont even need the checkmark, but even if I remove it (so only the Image remains) the Image is not displayed